# In practice, does crypto software accept a *.com or or even a *. certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, man-in-the-middle, validation

Assuming this will be done with your own PKI, and not a public trusted CA.

Considering that `*.sub.domain.com` is valid, and so is `*.domain.com` is valid, is it *technically* possible to issue `*.com` and even a `*.` certificate?

The certificate I'm investigating is a "*." certificate being used for any other domain name such as "https://google.com" and then performing MITM attacks.

Will any certificate validation framework support a `*.` certificate?  Will it be rejected outright, or will normal validation rules apply?

Comment: By "support", do you mean "is accepted" or "is accepted and matches every possible domain name"?

Comment: @curiousguy - updated... does it result in every possible match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [RFC-2818 - HTTP Over TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818):

> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by
> [RFC2459].  If more than one identity of a given type is present in
> the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one
> of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
> character * which is considered to match any single domain name
> component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but
> not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.

So I believe it would be possible to do something like have a certificate that matches a very wide variety of URLS: `*.com`, `www.*.com`, and `ssl.*.com`.  You may want to try [double-wildcard certificates](https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain) (e.g., match `*.*.com`), but most browsers will not (and should not) accept them.

I also would not be the least bit surprised if modern browsers disallowed wild cards in the next level down from top level domain (e.g., `*.com`).

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible to make a certificate which contains a name "*.com" but, as per [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) (section 3.1), a wildcard matches one domain component, not several (i.e. it would be valid for "example.com" but not for "www.example.com"). However, there is a difference between the specification, and what implementers do of it. There are [reports](http://wiki.cacert.org/WildcardCertificates) that *some* browsers accept to match a wildcard with *several* domain components (i.e. "*.example.com" matching "sub.www.example.com").

Moreover, most modern Web browser include failsafes, which reject overly broad wildcard certificates. See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6873/can-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-be-issued-for-a-second-level-domain): "*.com" and even "*.co.uk" will be refused by browsers, even if RFC 2818 would not have seen any problem with that.