# Is or was it possible to register a wildcard certificate to third level subdomain?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, man-in-the-middle, c

The use of a null byte in a certificate cn is [very well known](http://hackaday.com/2009/07/29/black-hat-2009-breaking-ssl-with-null-characters/)…

and I saw this code in a popular smtp server *(who obviously thought it didn’t worth to use the gnutls or openssl for doing that kind of thing)* :

```
static bool
does_name_match(const char * name, const char * pat) {
char * cp;
return *pat == '*'      /* possible wildcard match */
  ?    *++pat == '.'        /* starts star, dot              */
    && !strchr(++pat, '*')  /* has no more stars             */
    && strchr(pat, '.') /* and has another dot.          */
    && (cp = strchr(name, '.'))/* The name has at least one dot */
    && strcmp(++cp, pat) == 0 /* and we only compare after it. */
  :    !strchr(pat+1, '*')
    && strcmp(name, pat) == 0;
}
```

which will prevent the recognition of`*.\0.thoughtcrime.org`or`*.*\0.thoughtcrime.org`with`tip.email`will trigger a match in the case of`*.fmm.email\0.thoughtcrime.org`with`mail.fmm.email`

So is it, or was it, possible to register something like`*.e10000.biz\0.thoughtcrime.org` *(since e10000 and biz can be considered as usual words and not only subdomain)*

Comment: I use also`was`because I think`ca`should normally reject the registration of null byte in a domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at google certificate’s, it’s now very clear…

The answer is yes of course since you can request to be a certificate authority for the domains you control…